# MS Access - Standardising data to a probability distribution

Tags: ms-access

I have a very large data set (10 minutes wind speed observations over 10 years) which I want to compare by way of a normalised / standardised S curve / probability distribution to different data sets with far less records. In Excel I'd sort the data by wind speed (lowest to highest) take the record / row number, divide by the total number of records / rows and get 2 normalised probability distributions from P0 to P100 to compare (then graph with y axis speed and x axis from 0 to 100).

Table is analysis, Query is Master with fields "Timestamp", "Average wind speed ms".  Would like Excel to be able to get 100 records (time and speed) from Access at P0, P1 .... P100 for comparing to same output from another query with same fields.  Or combine the two lots of speed data into one query with 100 records with Px wind speed from A and Px wind speed from B on same row.

Comment: Please try to include a clear description of what you are trying to achieve, what have you tried yourself, where do things go wrong. Your current question does not provide sufficient detail to allow people to assist you. Try to edit your question to include more details on the exact problem your trying to solve.

Comment: If QUERY 1 was SELECT TOP 5 PERCENT Master.[Average Wind Speed] FROM MASTER GROUP BY Master.[Average Wind Speed] ORDER BY Master.[Average Wind Speed] and QUERY2 was SELECT Max ([Average wind speed]) from QUERY1, that max value would be one value for new query, and rerun for TOP 6, TOP 7, TOP 8 etc would be the next data points.  So I want to pick out every n/100 th wind speed record where n is the total number of records in the query. If there were 200 records I would want every 2nd, if there where 500 I would want every 5th etc. That allows a set of say 12356 to be compared to a set of 7203